# NIC Bonding works but can't ping

Tags: bonding

I have bonded two NICs(Intel I-350) on CentOS 6.4. The configuration looks fine, but I am not able to ping any host and switch in its subnet.

===Bond0 status===

cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.6.0 (September 26, 2009)

Bonding Mode: transmit load balancing
Primary Slave: None
Currently Active Slave: eth1
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 80
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth1
 MII Status: up
 Speed: 1000 Mbps
 Duplex: full
 Link Failure Count: 0
 Permanent HW addr: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b9
 Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth2
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:ba
Slave queue ID: 0

===Interface===

> bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:B9
>             inet addr:192.168.100.2  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe95:cab9/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:6162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:369234 (360.5 KiB)
>
> eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:B9
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:3106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:185754 (181.4 KiB)
>             Memory:dfb40000-dfb60000
>
> eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:BA
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:3056 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:183480 (179.1 KiB)
>             Memory:dfb20000-dfb40000

===Message log when ifup bond0===

> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: bonding: bond0: Setting MII monitoring interval to 80.
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: bonding: bond0: setting mode to balance-tlb (5).
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: bonding: bond0: Setting MII monitoring interval to 80.
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: bonding: bond0: setting mode to balance-tlb (5).
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: bonding: bond0: Adding slave eth1.
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth1
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: bonding: bond0: enslaving eth1 as an active interface with a down link.
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: bonding: bond0: Adding slave eth2.
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth2
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: bonding: bond0: enslaving eth2 as an active interface with a down link.
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): bond0: link is not ready
>
> Apr  3 11:01:52 HOSTNAME kernel: 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device bond0
>
> Apr  3 11:01:55 HOSTNAME kernel: igb: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
>
> Apr  3 11:01:55 HOSTNAME kernel: bond0: link status definitely up for interface eth1, 1000 Mbps full duplex.
>
> Apr  3 11:01:55 HOSTNAME kernel: bonding: bond0: making interface eth1 the new active one.
>
> Apr  3 11:01:55 HOSTNAME kernel: bonding: bond0: first active interface up!
>
> Apr  3 11:01:55 HOSTNAME kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): bond0: link becomes ready
>
> Apr  3 11:01:56 HOSTNAME kernel: igb: eth2 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
>
> Apr  3 11:01:56 HOSTNAME kernel: bond0: link status definitely up for interface eth2, 1000 Mbps full duplex.
>
> Apr  3 11:01:58 HOSTNAME ntpd[2338]: Listening on interface #8 bond0, fe80::225:90ff:fe95:cab9#123 Enabled
>
> Apr  3 11:01:58 HOSTNAME ntpd[2338]: Listening on interface #9 bond0, 192.168.100.2#123 Enabled

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. After I changed the bonding mode from 5(balance-tlb) to 4(802.3ad), it works now.